# Wordpress theme to support single website but with 3 sections for 3 languages

Tags: multisite, themes, multi-language

I have 3 domains that go around the same topic - city portal. These domains are basically aimed at 3 languages: local, English and (just for the sake of argument): Esperanto.

I want to organize these domains in such a manner that, depending on the domain used, my visitors land onto a respective section. Each of the sections would be, so to say, independent of the other two. Of course, I might provide links to the other sections but that's another story.

On the other hand, I might even want to apply similar but completely different themes to these sections. Since a single Wordpress theme wouldn't work here, is it possible to create multi-site Wordpress installation on one's own VPS server and then apply separate themes on each of them?

If so, what are the drawbacks of multi-wp approach?

Comment: Have you looked into [MultilingualPress](https://multilingualpress.org/)? It works with a MultiSite setup

Comment: As to themes, yes, MultiSite supports different themes on each subsite.